# syntax error: unexpected end of file- unix

Tags: unix, csh

I am working on my unix homework but I get an error and I couldn't fix. Can anyone please help me?

*myCalc is a very simple calculator. operand1 and operand2 are integers. operator is the words plus, minus, div, and times.  The operands and operators will be passed on the command line. Generate error messages if the operands are not valid or the operator is not valid. If no arguments are passed show the usage statement.*

```
if ( $2 =~ "plus" ) then
        @ c = $1 + $3
        echo "The sum is: $c"

else if ( $2 =~ "minus" ) then
        @ c = $1 - $3
        echo "The difference is: $c"

else if ( $2 =~ "div" ) then
        @ c = $1 / $3
        echo "The quotient is: $c"

else if ( $2 =~ "times" ) then
        @ c = $1 * $3
        echo "The product is: $c"

else    echo "You have entered an invalid operation"
        exit 2


if ( $# < 3 ) then
        echo "You are missing an operand or operator"
        exit 1 
endif
```

Comment: Need an `endif` after `exit 2`.

Comment: I tried that but i still get the same error message, syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Works fine for me.  Make sure you have a carriage return after the last line.